# Is it legal to create a non-profit organization-style for-profit organization in the US?

Tags: corporate-law

Non-profit organizations can establish some rules by its members within the organization, for example, how members elect administrative officials such as the president, and the procedure to change rules. This, as far as I know, is not quite true in for-profit organizations, whose major decisions lie in owners of these organizations.

Is it legally possible to create such type of for-profit organizations with these non-profit organization features in the US? If so, is there a real-world example?

Comment: Are you asking if employees or customers instead of investors can own for-profit corporations? (They can and are sometimes called co-operatives or mutual companies in this situation.) Members are the "owners" of a typical non-profit, and shareholder-investors are the usual owners of a for-profit. If I'm wrong, what do you mean?

Comment: @ohwilleke Yes, you are right.